# iOS moveRowAtIndexPath a UITableView not save

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

I have a UITableView that reads data from a sql db.
When I reorder the data it only changes the top and bottom ones

Dragging 1 from top to bottom

When I Done an exit application and again open app previous changes are not saved?

image:

[image]

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath {


    id buffer = [MyObject objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [MyObject removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
    [MyObject insertObject:buffer atIndex:toIndexPath.row];


}

- (void)setEditing:(BOOL)editing animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setEditing:editing animated:animated];
    if (!editing) {
        //save here
        [self.managedObjectContext save:nil];
    }
}
```

Comment: What is `MyObject`? Do the calls to `removeObject` and `insertObject` actually persist the data changes?

Comment: @property (strong)NSMutableArray*MyObject; Not. actually persist the data changes

Comment: OK. So you just update an array when moving the row. Why do you expect that to survive app runs? You need to persists the data changes to the database.

Comment: You, sample code or video

Comment: After moving the cell , post your MyObject, to see if the indexing is proper